# Android build flavors with different Applications

Tags: android, android-productflavors, stetho

I'm trying to separate debug and release functionality in my app. For instance I'm using Stetho and Mortar libraries. They both require overridden Application class. But I would like Stetho to be accessible only in debug build. There are at least two approaches:

Have `MyApplication` class in release and debug flavors with different code. But in this case code which should be user in release build is duplicated.

`MyDebugApplication` extends `MyApplication` and contains only debug related stuff. In this case two Manifest files are required and merged some how.

So I'm wondering which approach is more efficient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You totally should use two base `MyBaseApplication` classes in the release and debug flavor and then extend the `MyApplication` class on your main scope.

This way the logic woun't be duplicated, and you'll have two different behaviours on debug and release.

Comment: small note: you have to put the MyApplication classes in the same package so you can use only one manifest file :)

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a different approach. I use config to determine what is turned on.. here is a simple version:

```
   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      Stetho.initialize(Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(app)
              .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(app))
              .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(app))
              .build());
      Timber.d("Stetho configured");
    }
```

But imagine instead of just BuildConfig.DEBUG you use a boolean resource:

`app.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.stetho_enabled)`

with:

`<bool name="wallet_production">true</bool>`

in a `settings.xml` resource file, or something... you can even get fancier and have this backed by an Optimizely live variable or the like.

I prefer this because then if I need to turn on Stetho or logging or something else in a release build, it's as easy as changing an xml file.

Comment: This approach keeps library in in production build.
In case you use lib only in debug builds your final apk file is smaller.

Comment: fair enough, if that is a concern for you. In our case it's worth the little bit of extra size for the flexibility and reduced complexity